# What significance does the movie 'Lord of the Flies' have to the real world?

Tags: lord-of-the-flies

I have watched the movie and that's about it, I have heard about how it is so significant, but what is it significant to?.

I understand it's about some boys on an evacuation plane flight from war, their plane crashes and they end up on an Island, left to survive or die.

Here is a passage of the [plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord_of_the_Flies):

> In the midst of a wartime evacuation, a British aeroplane crashes on or near an isolated island in a remote region of the Pacific Ocean. The only survivors are boys in their middle childhood or preadolescence. Two boys—the fair-haired Ralph and an overweight, bespectacled boy nicknamed "Piggy"—find a conch, which Ralph uses as a horn to convene all the survivors to one area. Ralph is optimistic, believing that grown-ups will come to rescue them but Piggy realizes the need to organize: ("put first things first and act proper"). Because Ralph appears responsible for bringing all the survivors together, he immediately commands some authority over the other boys and is quickly elected their "chief". He does not receive the votes of the members of a boys' choir, led by the red-headed Jack Merridew, although he allows the choir boys to form a separate clique of hunters. Ralph establishes three primary policies: to have fun, to survive, and to constantly maintain a smoke signal that could alert passing ships to their presence on the island and thus rescue them. The boys establish a form of democracy by declaring that whoever holds the conch shall also be able to speak at their formal gatherings and receive the attentive silence of the larger group.
>
> Jack organises his choir into a hunting party responsible for discovering a food source. Ralph, Jack, and a quiet, dreamy boy named Simon soon form a loose triumvirate of leaders with Ralph as the ultimate authority. Upon inspection of the island, the three determine that it has fruit and wild pigs for food. The boys also use Piggy's spectacles to create a fire. Though he is Ralph's only real confidant, Piggy is quickly made into an outcast by his fellow "biguns" (older boys) and becomes an unwilling source of laughs for the other children while being hated by Jack. Simon, in addition to supervising the project of constructing shelters, feels an instinctive need to protect the "littluns" (younger boys).
>
> The semblance of order quickly deteriorates as the majority of the boys turn idle; they give little aid in building shelters, spend their time having fun and begin to develop paranoias about the island. The central paranoia refers to a supposed monster they call the "beast", which they all slowly begin to believe exists on the island. Ralph insists that no such beast exists, but Jack, who has started a power struggle with Ralph, gains a level of control over the group by boldly promising to kill the creature. At one point, Jack summons all of his hunters to hunt down a wild pig, drawing away those assigned to maintain the signal fire. A ship travels by the island, but without the boys' smoke signal to alert the ship's crew, the vessel continues without stopping. Ralph angrily confronts Jack about his failure to maintain the signal; in frustration Jack assaults Piggy, breaking his glasses. The boys subsequently enjoy their first feast. Angered by the failure of the boys to attract potential rescuers, Ralph considers relinquishing his position as leader, but is convinced not to do so by Piggy, who both understands Ralph's importance and deeply fears what will become of him should Jack take total control.
>
> One night, an aerial battle occurs near the island while the boys sleep, during which a fighter pilot ejects from his plane and dies in the descent. His body drifts down to the island in his parachute; both get tangled in a tree near the top of the mountain. Later on, while Jack continues to scheme against Ralph, the twins Sam and Eric, now assigned to the maintenance of the signal fire, see the corpse of the fighter pilot and his parachute in the dark. Mistaking the corpse for the beast, they run to the cluster of shelters that Ralph and Simon have erected to warn the others. This unexpected meeting again raises tensions between Jack and Ralph. Shortly thereafter, Jack decides to lead a party to the other side of the island, where a mountain of stones, later called Castle Rock, forms a place where he claims the beast resides. Only Ralph and a quiet suspicious boy, Roger, Jack's closest supporter, agree to go; Ralph turns back shortly before the other two boys but eventually all three see the parachutist, whose head rises via the wind. They then flee, now believing the beast is truly real. When they arrive at the shelters, Jack calls an assembly and tries to turn the others against Ralph, asking them to remove Ralph from his position. Receiving no support, Jack storms off alone to form his own tribe. Roger immediately sneaks off to join Jack, and slowly an increasing amount of older boys abandon Ralph to join Jack's tribe. Jack's tribe continues to lure recruits from the main group by promising feasts of cooked pig. The members begin to paint their faces and enact bizarre rites, including sacrifices to the beast. One night, Ralph and Piggy decide to go to one of Jack's feasts.
>
> Simon, who faints frequently and is likely an epileptic,[6][7] has a secret hideaway where he goes to be alone. One day while he is there, Jack and his followers erect a faux sacrifice to the beast nearby: a pig's head, mounted on a sharpened stick and soon swarming with scavenging flies. Simon conducts an imaginary dialogue with the head, which he dubs the "Lord of the Flies". The head mocks Simon's notion that the beast is a real entity, "something you could hunt and kill", and reveals the truth: they, the boys, are the beast; it is inside them all. The Lord of the Flies also warns Simon that he is in danger, because he represents the soul of man, and predicts that the others will kill him. Simon climbs the mountain alone and discovers that the "beast" is the dead parachutist. He rushes down to tell the other boys, who are engaged in a ritual dance. The frenzied boys mistake Simon for the beast, attack him, and beat him to death. Both Ralph and Piggy participate in the melee, and they become deeply disturbed by their actions after returning from Castle Rock.
>
> Jack and his rebel band decide that the real symbol of power on the island is not the conch, but Piggy's glasses—the only means the boys have of starting a fire. They raid Ralph's camp, confiscate the glasses, and return to their abode on Castle Rock. Ralph, now deserted by most of his supporters, journeys to Castle Rock to confront Jack and secure the glasses. Taking the conch and accompanied only by Piggy, Sam, and Eric, Ralph finds the tribe and demands that they return the valuable object. Confirming their total rejection of Ralph's authority, the tribe capture and bind the twins under Jack's command. Ralph and Jack engage in a fight which neither wins before Piggy tries once more to address the tribe. Any sense of order or safety is permanently eroded when Roger, now sadistic, deliberately drops a boulder from his vantage point above, killing Piggy and shattering the conch. Ralph manages to escape, but Sam and Eric are tortured by Roger until they agree to join Jack's tribe.
>
> Ralph secretly confronts Sam and Eric, who warn him that Jack and Roger hate him and that Roger has sharpened a stick at both ends, implying the tribe intends to hunt him like a pig and behead him. The following morning, Jack orders his tribe to begin a hunt for Ralph. Jack's savages set fire to the forest while Ralph desperately weighs his options for survival. Following a long chase, most of the island is consumed in flames. With the hunters closely behind him, Ralph trips and falls. He looks up at a uniformed adult—a British naval officer whose party has landed from a passing warship to investigate the fire. Ralph bursts into tears over the death of Piggy and the *"end of innocence"*. Jack and the other children, filthy and unkempt, also revert to their true ages and erupt into sobs. The officer expresses his disappointment at seeing British boys exhibiting such feral, warlike behaviour before turning to stare awkwardly at his own warship.

Apparently this all has some meaning to it.

**What is the significance behind the movie Lord of the Flies?**

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to quote seven paragraphs from Wikipedia. Could you either condense it or just link to it?

Comment: Close it, I don't want this question up.

Comment: @natural fixing it sound like better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Lord of the Flies* (both the film and book) are significant in a few ways...

One is that the boys ultimately split into two factions, and because of the behavioral differences between factions, the work explores **nature vs nurture with the differences between those that seek to care for others and general survival everyone and those that seek to control**, dominate, or destroy forcing a survival of the fittest scenario--and what happens when it iS forced onto from one human being or group onto another???

Here is someone's essay on Nature vs Nurture: https://www.megaessays.com/viewpaper/94850.html

Another aspect of the story that I think is even more relevant to a contemporary first world country, like America, would be the symbolism of "Piggy" as the novel uses the "fat boy", in relation to the survival of fittest aspect and the notion of **"innocence lost"**. I would imagine that this character's persecution would hit home more than it may have at the time it was written, given the attention we give to the concept of **"fat-shaming"**.

This leads me to the fact that novel/film is also a musing on wartime, as it was written in 1954, which is after WWII and during the beginnings of The Cold war. The boys ultimately descend into savagery and thus retains war themes through out and shows the true evils of the human condition that seemingly is how William Golding felt about the brutality of WWII.

> Golding followed his parents’ wishes until his second year at Oxford,
>   when he changed his focus to English literature. After graduating from
>   Oxford, he worked briefly as a theater actor and director, wrote
>   poetry, and then became a schoolteacher. **In 1940, a year after England
>   entered World War II, Golding joined the Royal Navy, where he served
>   in command of a rocket-launcher and participated in the invasion of
>   Normandy.**
>
> **Golding’s experience in World War II had a profound effect on his view
>   of humanity and the evils of which it was capable.** After the war,
>   Golding resumed teaching and started to write novels. His first and
>   greatest success came with Lord of the Flies (1954), which ultimately
>   became a bestseller in both Britain and the United States after more
>   than twenty publishers rejected it. The novel’s sales enabled Golding
>   to retire from teaching and devote himself fully to writing....
>
> Lord of the Flies tells the story of a group of English schoolboys
>   marooned on a tropical island after their plane is shot down during a
>   war. Though the novel is fictional, **its exploration of the idea of
>   human evil is at least partly based on Golding’s experience with the
>   real-life violence and brutality of World War II**...
>   http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/flies/context.html

And lastly, Lord of the Flies is full of both **Christian and Greek Allegories**:

> What’s amazing, is the way that Golding managed to seamlessly
>   integrate multiple symbols throughout his novel to increase the impact
>   and meaning of his work. The entire novel is one big “web of ironies”
>   that uses symbols from Christianity alongside Greek Mythology and
>   Ideology (Talon 1). This website will present several analyses of the
>   various symbols and their backgrounds, that amplify Golding’s dark
>   perception of mankind.

Here is a website dedicated to both:
http://gclotf.weebly.com/

Comment: Agree with the answer, but I'm not sure why you're bringing up nature vs nurture. That's not what the story focuses about. The groups do not segregate in "nature" and "nurture", they separate into the more common good and evil archetypes (those who respect others, and those who do not). If anything, the entire island experience is solely about "nature", in the sense that a group of innocent children are able to independently create the same savagery that humans have historically incited. It's in the children's nature, their nurture has no part in it.

Comment: @Flater If you see the link I provide, I'm not the only one who believes that nature vs nurture is another theme of the novel, as this person wrote a five web-page essay on it, I presume for study. I don't disagree with you on the archetypes good vs evil theme, which is heavily alluded in allegories, but if you were looking at LOTF through a contemporary lens, where we have more science to back this up, one would wonder why some kids/people are inherently good vs inherently evil and how civilization plays into a nature vs nurture argument vs war!

Comment: Here's another link on nature vs nurture in LOTF: https://www.majortests.com/essay/Nature-Versus-Nurture-And-Island-532504.html

Comment: I see your point. I think the difference is whether you are focusing on the **content** of the story, or the **intended message**  of the story (that is never explicitly stated, but intended to be derived from the events). Similarly, Animal Farm is about an actual animal farm, but it is an allegory for the rise (and fall) of communism, even though the story itself never explicitly mentions communism.

Comment: @Flater - perhaps the juxtaposition is that "nurture" dominates the children when they are first stranded, and as they have to adapt to survival, on their own, without guidance or supervision they've always had, human "nature" re-asserts itself, in both good an bad ways.

Comment: @Flater true, but the question was how is the film significant, which is a matter of opinion in terms of prioritizing it's themes, as one may have to look to nature and nurture to even begin ask (as a 21st century reader) about if there are inherent natures vs conditioning of man to even conclude a good vs evil survival story. I only gave some ways I remembered the story being significant (with works sited to back me up)--surely there are other themes or ideas that I have forgotten and/or failed to better articulate.

Comment: @DarthLocke: I agree with you. Your initial phrasing had me confused: "One is that the boys ultimately split into two factions and therefor the work explores nature vs nurture". The quick succession of "split into two" and "nature vs nurture" made me think you were saying the groups split off into "nature" vs "nurture", which didn't make sense.